# Как найти сумму ряда?

Tags: c++, математика

Дано натуральное число x и количество рядов равное 5 как вывести сумму ряда?
[image: Соотношения]

Вот мой код:

```
// найти сумму ряда
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    double x;
    cout << "x=";
    cin >> x;
    for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
    {
        double a = x, s = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n * 2; i += 2)
        {
            a *= -1 * (x * x) / (2*i*(2*i-1));
            s += a;
        }
        cout << "N=" << n << "  S=" << s << endl;
    }
}
```

И вот что выводит в результате:[image: Вывод]
Помогите пожалуйста исправить формулу чтобы она выводила верные цифры.

Comment: вы один и тот же вопрос дублировать будете?

Comment: @Zhihar,да есть такое,но портить тот вопрос не хочется.Мне просто нужно исправить формулу...

Comment: так вы его не испортите - вы же можете добавить как ответ на свой ответили свой вопрос модифицировать, дописать  - так более информативно будет

Comment: @Zhihar Здесь формула чуть другая,и я немного туплю с её модификацией...Просто всё дело в этой одной строчке,так бы я не задавал вопрос если бы сам смог разобраться:)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте посмотрим `a(n + 1)` и `a(n)`

```
a(n) = (-1)^n * x^(2n + 2) / (2n + 2)!

a(n+1) = (-1)^(n+1) * x^(2(n+1) + 2) / (2(n+1) + 2)! = (-1)^n * x^(2n + 4) / (2n + 4)!
```

значит

```
a(n+1)/a(n) = -1 * x^2 / (2n + 3)(2n + 4)
```

или если считать от `a(n+1)`:

```
a(n)/a(n-1) = -1 * x^2 / (2(n-1) + 3)(2(n-1) + 4) = -1 * x^2 / (2n + 1)(2n + 2)
```

Смотрим ваш код:

```
a *= -1 * (x * x) / (2*i*(2*i-1));
```

и вот ваше `(2*i*(2*i-1))` вроде как не похоже на `(2i + 1)(2i + 2)`

проверьте меня на всякий случай

Код:

```
double x = 2;

double part = x * x / 2; // f(n = 0)
double sum = 0;

for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++)
{
    part *= -1 * (x * x) / ((2 * n + 1) * (2 * n + 2));
    sum += part;

    cout << "N = " << n << "  S = " << sum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Zhihar,нет не проходит,выдаёт такие цифры:-9.6,330667 и прочую ерунду которая не соответствует таблице:(

Comment: @Юрий, потому что дополнительно вы еще и с кодом перемудрили. Посмотрите - я в конце ответа привёл свой код и сравните со своим

Comment: Zhihar,ваш код довольно сильно отличается от моего.В моём x вводится а в вашем строго задана,плюс у вас есть строчка x*x/2 которая у меня вообще отсутствует.Спасибо вам за помощь и постараюсь не дублировать вопросы.

Comment: @Юрий, вы меня удивляете!!! Зачем мне писать ввод от пользователя, если моя задача проверить сам алгоритм - т.е. в моем коде замените `double x = 2;` на `double x; std::cin >> x` - это же ОЧЕВИДНО!!!! касательно того, что `x*x/2` - потому что это нулевой член последовательности (при n = 0) и от него ИТЕРАЦИОННО будет вычисляться остальные члены! и это тоже ОЧЕВИДНО. Опять же вы спрашиваете `что надо исправить в моем коде чтобы работало` - я показываю что надо исправить - переписать код, удалив лишнюю математику и исправив формулу. Конечно мой код отличается хотя бы тем, что ОН РАБОТАЕТ :)

Comment: не надо усложнять код сверх меры - от этого как раз и лезут ошибки и появляется недопонимание где они

Comment: Zhihar,учту при выполнении последующих своих задач.

Comment: @Юрий, если задача на бумаге занимает пару строчек, то в коде она тоже не должна быть большой - отталкивайтесь от этого - на бумаге есть легко показать зависимость `f(n) = f(n-1) * -1 * x^2 / (2x +1)(2x+2)` и все, никаких дополнительных циклов не нужно, поэтому и в коде смело делайте также